# Appending JQuery to Wicket Component

Tags: jquery, wicket

I'm testing out appending javascript to my wicket componets and it seems to work ok. But when I make it a jquery function it doesn't work.

Other jquery functions work ok and I have the library. I want to add script to each component as it is added to the page.

```
ExternalLink taricLink = new ExternalLink(
                "tariclink",
                "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/taric/taric_consultation.jsp?Lang=en");
        final String tar = "taricLink" + Integer.toString(taricNum);
        taricLink.setOutputMarkupId(true).setMarkupId(
                "taricLink" + Integer.toString(taricNum));
```

From reading articles this was the way I found:

```
taricLink.add(new AbstractAjaxBehavior() {
            @Override
            public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
                String js = "$(#" + tar + ").click(function(){"
                        + "alert(\"hello\")" + "});";
                response.renderOnDomReadyJavascript(js);
            }
            public void onRequest() {
            }

        });

        add(taricLink);
```

And in the html:

```
<a href="#" wicket:id="tariclink" target='_blank'>TARIC</a>
```

Comment: I would like to help, but I do not understand what do you expect? What is the expected result? To have few links in a page those have a special onclick listener added by jQuery?

Comment: So, I'm trying to add a different jquery function to the page each time I add a new panel.

Step 1. I add a new panel. Each panel has 13 components.
Step 2. I add a JQuery function which targets 3 of the components. I give the 3 components unique markup that I can target.
Step 3. I don't know how many times the user will add a new panel. So I must create unique markup for the 3 components each time, then I add JQuery which targets the 3 components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something to happen when clicking the link then you need to use an `AjaxEventBehavior` like this:

```
private ExternalLink taricLink() {
    final String url = "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/taric/taric_consultation.jsp?Lang=en";
    ExternalLink el = new ExternalLink("taricLink", url);
    el.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("click") {

        @Override
        protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget art) {
            art.appendJavaScript("alert('clicked')");
        }
    });
    return el;
}
```

You can in the `appendJavaScript` function execute some jQuery if you want.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I'll accept it because it answers the question, but looking back at it I was asking the wrong question. I mistakenly thought that I wanted it to be a behaviour, when I want the on click to come from the JQuery